# mpandroidchart X-Axis labels density when zoomed out

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a line chart like on photo below and I have X-Axis labels drawn on every single Y-Axis value. As it is now it makes it almost impossible to read.

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC0qY.jpg)

What I want is the X-Axis labels to be drawn like on this photo below, so not for a every single Y-Axis value but just few of them and when I zoom in, the rest of values will be shown dynamically.

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0yW.png)

I fallowed the guidie but didn't find anything about this issue.

EDIT:

My Chart options

```
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
        lineData.setDrawValues(false);
        lineData.setHighlightEnabled(true);

        chart.setData(lineData);                      
        chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(3);

        // description
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[2]);
        description.setText("");
        chart.setDescription(description);

        // X-Axis
        IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return x_data[(int)value];
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(formatter);
        chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

        chart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
        //chart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);

        //Y-Axis
        chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0f);
        chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0f);

        // avg line
        Cursor avg = dbHelper.getAvg(id);
        avg.moveToFirst();

        if (avg.moveToFirst()) {

            YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
            LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(avg.getFloat(0), "avg");
            ll.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);
            ll.setLineWidth(0.3f);
            ll.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ll.setTextSize(6f);
            leftAxis.addLimitLine(ll);
        }

        chart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(int count)`

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code

```
 mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(6);
```

It may help you!!

Comment: Nothing really happen after this line, there are still 9 XAxis values shown.

Comment: have you decrease the value ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Edited my post with my chart options. Any sugestion?